# How to upgrade to Android 4.1 for Galaxy Tab GT-P1000

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-tab

Is there anybody who tried upgrading from Android 2.2 on this device recently? Or do you consider it a wise decision in terms of risks / gains involved?

I found tutorials that seem pretty up to date:

http://www.androidauthority.com/galaxy-tab-p1000-clockworkmod-recovery-118602/

http://www.androidauthority.com/galaxy-tab-gt-p1000-gsm-android-4-1-1-cyanogenmod-10-cm10-nightly-unofficial-112424/

Comment: What's your question? If you're asking for opinions as to whether upgrading is a good idea or not, please note that we like questions that prompt answers that are based on fact, not opinion. ([FAQ])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take into consideration that the 4.1 system you'd be installing isnt a stock build, it is a ROM created by a developer. Cyanogenmod is generally pretty stable, but you would want to do your homework at the XDA Developers site to determine if there are any bugs or known issues, or how the performance of 4.1 is on your device by reading users' reviews.

This would also require you to root your phone, which may invalidate your warranty, which is another consideration.